# What are some good Qt related blogs/forums/sites to follow?

Tags: qt

What are some good Qt related blogs/forums/sites to follow so one can learn more about developing with Qt?
Also maybe some good (in terms of user interface richness) opensource apps that one can read the source code and learn from them.

Comment: Evileg.ru use google translation unless you know ru

Answer (score 4):

- [Qt Developer Network Forum](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums)
- [PlanetQt](http://planetqt.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this too.

[Qt-articles](http://qt-articles.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to mention for the french speaking community :

[qtfr](http://www.qtfr.org/)

and the qt subdomain of developpez :

[qt.developpez](http://qt.developpez.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Also http://www.qtcentre.org/content/ and its wiki may be usable

Answer (score 2):

[Qt forum](http://www.qtforum.org/index.html) is another option.

Answer (score 2):

http://qt-apps.org/ has a number of open source applications-source generally one of the download options.
http://planetkde.org/ is a kde blog aggregator but there is occasionaly some qt-only stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy this one too. 
http://ariya.blogspot.com/